# Postfix mail server (outbound) strategy

Tags: postfix, performance, email-server

I am about to setup a web application that consists of 2 app servers (running php/apache) and 2 db servers (ubuntu slices on slicehost).

The application will be sending approximately 5000 emails a day initially which will grow to 20k-100k within about 3 months as new features get rolled out.

I have never really administered a mail server before so I am not sure what kind of load will start impacting performance.

The mail server (postfix) will have spikes where it will go from 5 emails a minute, to 20k a minute. (although this might be staggered, lets assume its not staggered for now)

Given the basic outline above, do you think it would be **beneficial** to run another server (slice) which is purely a mail server (outbound, running postfix) thereby shifting all email load over to that server instead of the app servers. Or, is postfix efficient enough that there is no need and a separate server is possibly overkill?

If people could refrain from "Test it and see" that would be good, I am asking for people with experience to comment.

**Additional note:** *Postfix will only be sending email, receiving email will be handled by google apps.*

Comment: Only outgoing email? Or will the email server handle any incoming and need to deal with spam filtering?

Comment: Only outgoing. Incoming will be handled by google apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, 20k a minute is going to be straining the system a bit.  The bottleneck will be disk IO, with the system trying to write all the queue files and read them back and generally shuffle them all around, so a dedicated VM (or machine, with smokingly fast disks) is the way to go.  Given that your mail probably isn't all that important, putting the spool on a RAM disk will give you significant performance gains at the cost of losing your queue when the machine reboots.